# Can a mouse event detect the target via a svg <use> tag

Tags: javascript, svg

Consider the following situation where a svg `<use>` tag is used to place objects at a give point:

```
<def>
   <g id="my_link">
     <path id="shape_1" ...
     <path id="shape_2" ...
   </g>
</def>

<use href="#my_link" x=100, y=100 />
```

When I capture a click event and get the target, I only get the `<use>` tag. Is is possible to get the the underlying object (and its id)?

Comment: Nope. `<use />` is essentially taking a thing as a whole.

Comment: Which element has a `click` event?

Comment: The '<svg>' element. I then look for the target to decide what to do.

Comment: So, I will have to redesign, and place the group with a transformation instead.

Comment: Yes. You can consider the elements referenced by the `<use>` a mirage.  Although they are technically in the DOM, they are invisible to outside CSS and events.